# foreach($pitches as $pitch) with $pitch.$i

Tags: php, foreach

How can I **add $i** to var **$pitch** in below code.
Result should be

> $pitch1, $pitch2, $pitch3, etc.

```
$i = '1';
foreach($pitches as $pitch) {
    if($pitch->option_name == 'agent_pitch_'.$i) $pitch.$i = $pitch->option_value ;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://3v4l.org/fYlnb) what you are looking for? `$i = 1;
${'foo'.$i} = 'bar';

echo $foo1;`. Update: judging by the dup, yeah xD

Comment: YES! thanks a lot.
For Chris85: if somebody has posted my thread before then he is very good. Just coded this part in the last 30min as new code.

Comment: @jtermaat The dup isn't what you are trying to do?

Comment: New code doesn't mean unique code. It's very unlikely that you'll face an unseen problem / error. A duplicate doesn't have to be an exact copy of the problem. BTW, that 'thread' is from 2013...